# Is it safe to link against more than one Platform Toolset?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I am programming in C++ on Windows using Visual Studio 2019 and Qt.

I am using a library created by another programmer that depends on a 3rd party .dll that in turn depends on msvcp140.dll and vcruntime140.dll.

I have installed Platform Toolset Visual Studio 2015 (v140).
However I do not wish to link with this since it seems to prevent me from using ISO C++17 Standard (when I select Platform Toolset="Visual Studio 2015 (v140)" the C++ Language Standard option is removed).

**Is it safe to mix Platform Toolset: "Visual Studio 2015 (v140)" and "Visual Studio 2019 (v142)"?**

The other programmer claims so. He has made sure that his API does not use any std class (e.g. string) as input or output.
Is this sufficient or is there something else I have to think of?

Comment: [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/potential-errors-passing-crt-objects-across-dll-boundaries).

Comment: It is fine to use v142, they made it backwards compatible since VS2015.

Answer (score 3):

As Hans Passant says, you can continue to use V142 for your VS2015 library. Hope [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160) could help you:

*The runtime libraries and apps compiled by any of these versions of the compiler are binary-compatible. It's reflected in the C++ toolset major number, which is 14 for all three versions. (The toolset version is v140 for Visual Studio 2015, v141 for 2017, and v142 for 2019). **Say you have third-party libraries built by Visual Studio 2015. You can still use them in an application built by Visual Studio 2017 or 2019.** There's no need to recompile with a matching toolset. The latest version of the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable package (the Redistributable) works for all of them.*